# No source injection for FormDataContentDisposition

Tags: jersey, jetty, jax-rs, multipart

I'm creating upload service with Jersey 2.5.1.

public class JerseyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

```
    public JerseyApplication() {
        register(RequestContextFilter.class);
        register(MultiPartFeature.class);
        packages("com.my.app");
        packages(JerseyApiDeclarationProvider.class.getPackage().getName());
        register(JacksonFeature.class);
    }
}
```

and the `Resource` for the upload is as follows:

```
@Path("api/admin/image")
@Produces(APPLICATION_JSON)
@Component
public class ImageUploadResource {

   @POST
   @Path("/upload")
   @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
   public String upload(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream fileInputStream,
                        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition contentDispositionHeader) {
      return contentDispositionHeader.getFileName();
   }
}
```

My Maven dependencies include

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

But starting up the application fails with:

```
[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.lang.String com.my.app.resource.ImageUploadResource.upload(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition) at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.my.app.resource.ImageUploadResource, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@1f5894ee]}, definitionMethod=public java.lang.String com.sanoma.avain.resource.ImageUploadResource.upload(java.io.InputStream,com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition), parameters=[Parameter [type=class java.io.InputStream, source=file, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition, source=file, defaultValue=null]], responseType=class java.lang.String}, nameBindings=[]}']
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:444)
```

From all the examples I've found this should be pretty standard way and I've only found solutions where they were missing the `jersey-media-multipart` dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was a typical [PEBCAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_error). We had Swagger as a dependency in our project. And Swagger uses a really old version of Jersey and an old version of Jersey2. So I ended up with a project where some of my imports where from one Jersey version and rest from another. This causes lots of weird behavior as things work almost but not quite.